# ADODB.Connection not reflecting current data set fields; '[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 11

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

Below mentioned sample procedure use to read data from input excel files saved in a folder. The SQl query has join operations from few tables (sheets) which are part of **reportWorkbook**.

After running this procedure successfully on some files at some stage it throws an error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 11.

for next input file.

```
Sub RunQueryOnInputFiles()

    Dim fldr            As Folder
    Dim fil             As File
    Dim oConn           As ADODB.Connection
    Dim oRs             As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim tmpWkb          As Workbook
    Dim reportWorkbook  As Workbook
    Dim sSql            As String

    Set reportWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
    reportWorkbook.Save tmpFilePath

    'Loop through all files in input folder

    For Each fil In fldr.Files                                              
        Set tmpWkb = Workbooks.Open(fil.Path)
        tmpWkb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        reportWorkbook.Sheets("TmpSheet").Range("A1").Paste xlPasteValues   
        'Paste input data
        tmpWkb.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Set oConn = OpenConnection(reportWorkbook.FullName)
        sSql = GenrateSQL("SOME QUERY FROM SHEET [TmpSheet$]")              
        'Genrate SQL query from [TmpSheet$]`
        Set oRs = GetRecordset(sSql, oConn)
        reportWorkbook.Sheets("XYZ").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRs
        CloseConnection oConn
    Next fils

End Sub
```

I debug the problem separately using below mentioned procedure

```
Sub testing()
    Dim sSql As String
    Dim x As ADODB.Connection
    Dim r As Object
    Dim fl As Object
    sSql = "SELECT * FROM [TmpSheet$A1:U4]"
'considering reportWorkbook is in scope it is same workbook
    Set x = OpenConnection(reportWorkbook.FullName)    
    GetRecordset sSql, x
    Set r = GetRecordset(sSql, x)
    For Each fl In r.Fields
        Debug.Print fl.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Here, fl.Name is returning the names which belongs to previous file which is already processed and data on TmpSheet is already been overwritten. Running the same testing() procedure after a few minutes shows correct fields which are available in Tmpsheet.

It seems that connection cannot be refreshed. Please suggest some method which can enforce connection to be refresh in run time.

Answer (score 0):

From the post of your abbreviated code, the challenge you are facing is querying the very workbook you are processing which always reflects the snapshot of last saved instance.

Consider incorporating a [`Workbook.Save`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.save) method after processing each Excel file within the loop.

```
For Each fil In fldr.Files                                              
    ...

    reportWorkbook.Save
Next fils
```

Additionally, consider querying the current workbook in the loop to avoid the overhead of opening the file and copying and pasting values.

```
For Each fil In fldr.Files                                              
    ' QUERY CURRENT WORKBOOK
    Set oConn = OpenConnection(fil.Path)
    sSql = GenrateSQL("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]") 
    Set oRs = GetRecordset(sSql, oConn)
    reportWorkbook.Sheets("TmpSheet").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRs
    oRs.Close()
    CloseConnection oConn

    ' QUERY MASTER WORKBOOK
    Set oConn = OpenConnection(reportWorkbook.FullName)
    sSql = GenrateSQL("SOME QUERY FROM SHEET [TmpSheet$]")                      
    Set oRs = GetRecordset(sSql, oConn)
    reportWorkbook.Sheets("XYZ").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset oRs
    oRs.Close()
    CloseConnection oConn

    reportWorkbook.Save
Next fils
```

Additional Notes:

- It appears you are overwriting data in *XYZ* sheet with each iteration of loop if that is the intention. Add or change sheet to avoid this overwriting.
- If your sheets have headers, be sure to copy recordset starting in `A2` and loop field names starting in `A1` (like your `testing()` subroutine). Or use static headers in row 1.
- For bottom solution to query looped workbook, if sheet is not known in advance you will need to open document in loop to get sheet name and pass it into first SQL query.

Comment: XYZ sheet is vary based on input file.